# How to use SFINAE to make a polyfill for missing values in enum class?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, sfinae, enum-class

I thought this should be easy, but I've been struggling with it for a while so I thought I should ask here.

I want to make a template metafunction that takes a type corresponding to a C++11 enum class as its argument, and returns an int:

- If the enum class `E` has an enumerator value `a`, then return `static_cast<int>(E::a)`.
- If the enum class `E` does not have an enumerator value `a`, then return `42`.

Then I would like to make a template function that takes a run-time instance of some enum class `E`, static casts it to int, and checks if it matches this metafunction.

I tried many iterations of, templating a struct and use template partial specialization to try to distinguish if `E::a` exists, also using function templates... I'm not sure if I can reconstruct everything that I tried but here's the most recent iteration:

```
template <typename E>
inline int get_a_int_val(int result = E::a) { return result; }

template <typename E>
inline int get_a_int_val(int result = 42) { return result; }

template <typename E>
inline bool is_a_val(const E & input) {
  return static_cast<int>(input) == get_a_int_val<E>();
}
```

This doesn't work, because I'm redefining default arguments.

```
template <typename E, int result = E::a>
inline int get_a_int_val() { return result; }

template <typename E, int result = 42>
inline int get_a_int_val() { return result; }

template <typename E>
inline bool is_a_val(const E & input) {
  return static_cast<int>(input) == get_a_int_val<E>();
}
```

This doesn't work, because non-type parameters cannot depend on type parameters.

```
template <typename E>
struct get_a_int_val {
  static const int value = 42;
};

template <typename E>
struct get_a_int_val<E> {
  static const int value = static_cast<int>(E::a);
};

template <typename E>
inline bool is_a_val(const E & input) {
  return static_cast<int>(input) == get_a_int_val<E>::value;
}
```

This doesn't work, because

```
error: 
  class template partial specialization does not specialize any template
  argument; to define the primary template, remove the template argument
  list
```

What's the correct way to do this?

---

Motivation:

The reason that I want to do this is, I want to work around what seems to be a bug in libstdc++ which I reported here: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=68307

In C++11 in the `<system_error>` header, there are a bunch of enumerator values for `std::errc` which are supposed to be defined, however, on mingw some of them are missing. This causes compilation errors in my program because, depending on how `Asio` is configured, `lib::asio::errc` may be typedef'd to `std::errc`, and `websocketpp` assumes that `lib::asio::errc::operation_canceled` is a defined symbol. I wanted to throw together some kind of shim that I can put around that in the `websocketpp` code so that it will be defined acceptably on any platform (either to `lib::asio::errc::operation_canceled` if it exists, or to ECANCELED from `<cerrno>` if not.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in many ways, one of them is the following:

```
template <typename E, typename Enable = void>
struct get_a_int_val {
  static const int value = 42;
};

template <typename E>
struct get_a_int_val<E, typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<decltype(E::a), 
                                                decltype(E::a)>::value, void>::type>{
  static const int value = static_cast<int>(E::a);
};
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7f7b1705aec30451)

Answer (score 1):

You may create a traits for that:

```
template <typename E>
std::false_type has_a_impl(...);

template <typename E> auto has_a_impl(int) -> decltype(E::a, std::true_type{});

template <typename E>
using has_a = decltype(has_a_impl<E>(0));
```

And then use it in SFINAE:

```
template <typename E>
std::enable_if_t<has_a<E>::value, int>
get_a_int_val() { return static_cast<int>(E::a); }

template <typename E>
std::enable_if_t<!has_a<E>::value, int>
get_a_int_val() { return 42; }
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/6eq8ML)